# How to handle JS serialized item in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Hey guys!
I am having a bit of trouble handling the data from a submitted form that is serialized with JS.
In the form there a textarea fields which users can input any text they want but when they enter & like "apples & oranges", I have trouble handling that.  As we know that JS serializes & to %26 and spaces with a "+" sign.

So now back in PHP, I am trying to put this data into the database and call it back out elsewhere but for the life of me don't know how to handle the special characters properly.

Note that I am also php exploding the data at the "&" sign to make it into an array, then is put into the database as an array.  I tried several methods like urldecode, htmlentities but those don't help because remember I need to explode at "&".

I am serializing in JS because its an AJAX submitting form.

Comment: Can you not urldecode() and then explode()? or explode() with %26 as the delimiter?

Comment: Why are you serialising with JS?

Comment: Can you show us, how you serialize your data? I think, you could completely bypass this problem if you would build a proper POST request.

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have added I am AJAX submitting the form therefore I am serializing it.

Comment: I think nobody here will be able to help you, unless you post some of your code. For normally what you are describing shouldn't be a problem at all, if handled correctly.

Comment: i think you might want to convert it to Json before sending over http post/get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a double replace to prevent using a loop.

First I would replace all & to '####-####' or any other code that is highly unlikely to appear (or use chr(0)).

Then use urldecode() to replace all %26 to & and all + to ' '

Last explode on '####-####' instead of the &

Comment: Thanks Hugo your comment gave me an idea..I use what you said and then I used urldecode() after and it did the trick...

Answer (score 1):

What about [url**decode**](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)?

Comment: No that would not work because it changes it into "&" and I need the "&" to explode from...

Answer (score 1):

[`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 1):

If something is serialized in JS and then sent to a PHP script - it can only be via GET or POST method, which in return means that the serialized data will be stored in one of the following arrays: $_GET if method was GET, $_POST if method was POST and $_REQUEST regardless of the method (so you can capture both POST and GET variables with a single array).

That means that you shouldn't have your custom function that creates from and to php array since it's already done for you.
If you want to store the array in string format, you should serialize that array before storing it into the db and then unserialize it when you want to use it in array format after pulling it out from db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to get the text representation of those encoded characters. I doubt that JS is doing this by itself though.

Comment: No that would not work because it changes it into "&" and I need the "&" to explode from...